# How do I (help) translate not-yet-localized text in non-English versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: language-support, translation

In Ubuntu and Ubuntu-based systems like Elementary OS for example, I see sometimes text that are not translated from English to Swedish (my native language). How can I edit the translation?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official site](http://community.ubuntu.com/contribute/) you may help translating Ubuntu via [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/):

> If your first language is not English but you have strong English skills, you can make a huge contribution by helping to translate Ubuntu applications into your first language. Even if you just translate a few lines you can make a difference to someone in your own country who is learning about computers and free software.
>
> - Translate software in Ubuntu into your language using [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/rosetta). Join the [Ubuntu-Translators](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-translators) mailing list to stay in touch with other Ubuntu translators.
> - Translate documents written by the [documentation team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DocumentationTeam). This can also be done using [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-docs)
> - Discuss translation, fonts and other issues with your [local community team](http://community.ubuntu.com/help-information/meeting-other-ubuntu-users/).

Comment: ok, but can I edit the translation on an already installed system?

Comment: I think that depends very much on what specifically you want to translate - some apps keep localization data in XML or other serialized data format, so it's easily modifiable. With other it may be much more difficult. I think you might try to narrow down your question and then somebody will be able to come up with a concrete answer.